# Signifiance of fixed_frame parameter in lookupTransform function

Tags: navigation, transforms, ros-melodic, tf2-ros, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was going through the [implementation](http://docs.ros.org/en/jade/api/tf2_ros/html/c++/classtf2__ros_1_1Buffer.html#a01a57848abda3ddeb617655cb88f37d2) of the `lookupTransform` function defined inside the [base_local_planner::getGoalPose()](http://docs.ros.org/en/jade/api/base_local_planner/html/namespacebase__local__planner.html#aa0e40cef653b1dd1f828e2090c22b5b8) function.

What is the significance of the `fixed_frame` parameter in `tf2_ros::Buffer::lookupTransform (target_frame, target_time, source_frame, source_time, fixed_frame, timeout)`  function ?

The documentation mentions the following - Get the transform between two frames by frame ID assuming fixed frame.

What's preventing us to always go for the other [implementation](http://docs.ros.org/en/jade/api/tf2_ros/html/c++/classtf2__ros_1_1Buffer.html#acabbd72cae8f49fb3b6ede3be7e34c55) of `the lookupTransform` function -   `tf2_ros::Buffer::lookupTransform (target_frame, source_frame, time, timeout)` ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382463/signifiance-of-fixed_frame-parameter-in-lookuptransform-function/) by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 310 on 2021-07-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you use the advanced API you're transporting the data in time. As such you need to tell tf which coordinate frame it is considered fixed during the change in time.

There's tutorials on this in the [main tf2 tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials) for both [C++](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Time%20travel%20with%20tf2%20%28C%2B%2B%29) and [Python](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Time%20travel%20with%20tf2%20%28Python%29)

You can also read about it in the 2013 paper: http://wiki.ros.org/Papers/TePRA2013_Foote

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2021-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2